# Building a Neural Network using JAX

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, neural-network, jax

I tried to build a Neural network from scratch using JAX numpy moldule. In the training phase it seems that the accuracy of the model doesn't improve at all. Here is the code.

```
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp

def init_params():
    key = jax.random.PRNGKey(0)
    W1 = jax.random.uniform(key, (10, 784), minval=-0.5, maxval=0.5)
    b1 = jax.random.uniform(key, (10, 1), minval=-0.5, maxval=0.5)
    W2 = jax.random.uniform(key, (10, 10), minval=-0.5, maxval=0.5)
    b2 = jax.random.uniform(key, (10, 1), minval=-0.5, maxval=0.5)
    return W1, b1, W2, b2

def ReLU(Z):
    return jnp.maximum(Z, 0)

def softmax(Z):
    A = jnp.exp(Z) / jnp.sum(jnp.exp(Z))
    return A

def forward_prop(W1, b1, W2, b2, X):
    Z1 = jnp.dot(W1, X) + b1
    A1 = ReLU(Z1)
    Z2 = jnp.dot(W2, A1) + b2
    A2 = softmax(Z2)
    return Z1, A1, Z2, A2

def ReLU_deriv(Z):
    return Z > 0

def one_hot(Y):
    one_hot_Y = jnp.zeros((Y.size, Y.max() + 1))
    one_hot_Y = one_hot_Y.at[jnp.arange(Y.size), Y].set(1)
    return one_hot_Y.T


def backward_prop(Z1, A1, Z2, A2, W1, W2, X, Y):
    one_hot_Y = one_hot(Y)
    dZ2 = A2 - one_hot_Y
    dW2 = 1 / m * jnp.dot(dZ2, A1.T)
    db2 = 1 / m * jnp.sum(dZ2, axis=1, keepdims=True)
    dZ1 = jnp.dot(W2.T, dZ2) * ReLU_deriv(Z1)
    dW1 = 1 / m * jnp.dot(dZ1, X.T)
    db1 = 1 / m * jnp.sum(dZ1, axis=1, keepdims=True)
    return dW1, db1, dW2, db2

def update_params(W1, b1, W2, b2, dW1, db1, dW2, db2, alpha):
    W1 = W1 - alpha * dW1
    b1 = b1 - alpha * db1    
    W2 = W2 - alpha * dW2  
    b2 = b2 - alpha * db2    
    return W1, b1, W2, b2


def get_predictions(A2):
    return jnp.argmax(A2, 0)

def get_accuracy(predictions, Y):
    print(predictions, Y)
    return jnp.sum(predictions == Y) / Y.size

def gradient_descent(X, Y, alpha, iterations):
    W1, b1, W2, b2 = init_params()
    for i in range(iterations):
        Z1, A1, Z2, A2 = forward_prop(W1, b1, W2, b2, X)
        dW1, db1, dW2, db2 = backward_prop(Z1, A1, Z2, A2, W1, W2, X, Y)
        W1, b1, W2, b2 = update_params(W1, b1, W2, b2, dW1, db1, dW2, db2, alpha)
        if i % 10 == 0:
            print("Iteration: ", i)
            predictions = get_predictions(A2)
            print(get_accuracy(predictions, Y))
    return W1, b1, W2, b2


W1, b1, W2, b2 = gradient_descent(X_train, Y_train, 1e-3, 500)
```

I'm a complete newbie to JAX and I cannot solve this. What is the issue and how to solve this ?

I tried to change the weight updating function as it seems to have some problem with updating the model weights

Comment: Maybe, in your softmax function, you need to specify the axis parameter in the jnp.sum function to sum along the correct axis. (axis=0). I am not quite sure though

Comment: I posted it as an answer, I am glad to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your softmax function, you need to specify the `axis` parameter in the `jnp.sum` function to sum along the correct axis. Here's how:

```py
def softmax(Z):
    A = jnp.exp(Z) / jnp.sum(jnp.exp(Z), axis=0)
    return A
```

By specifying `axis=0`, you ensure that the exponential values are summed across the correct axis.